# How to prove an integral inequality in a ball

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I think the following inequality is correct. While I cannot prove it rigorously. Would someone help me to prove it? Thanks very much!

$$
\iint_{\{|y|\le R\}} \frac{1}{|x-y|^{n-1}} dy \le \iint_{\{|y|\le R\}} \frac{1}{|y|^{n-1}} dy 
$$
for any $x$ such that $|x|<R$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072732/obvious-integral-inequality-for-radially-decreasing-function?rq=1 for essentially the same question. The answer given there generalizes to your case.

Comment: Thank you very much!